# How to encode customized decimal object (e.g. generated by protobuf) to binary format using Ignite c++ thin-client

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, decimal, ignite

Unlike Ignite Java client
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/binary/BinaryWriter.html

C++ thin client doesn't come with write/read decimal methods.
I wonder how it can be achieved for decimal using c++ thin client.

Here's my BinaryType class template.

```
namespace ignite { namespace binary {
template <>
struct BinaryType<some_namespace::Product> : BinaryTypeDefaultAll<some_namespace::Product> {
  static void GetTypeName(std::string& dst) { dst = "PRODUCT_OMS_V1_TYPE"; };
  static void Write(BinaryWriter& writer, const some_namespace::Product& obj)
  {
    writer.WriteInt32("id", obj.id());
    writer.WriteString("name", obj.name());
    writer.WriteObject<some_namespace::DecimalValue>("price", obj.price());
  };
  static void Read(BinaryReader& reader, some_namespace::Product& dst)
  {
    dst.set_id(reader.ReadInt32("id"));
    dst.set_name(reader.ReadString("name"));
    dst.mutable_price()->CopyFrom(reader.ReadObject<some_namespace::DecimalValue>("price"));
  };
}} // namespace ignite::binary
```

some_namespace::Product is my compiled protobuf message

```
message Product {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  DecimalValue price = 3;
}

message DecimalValue {
  int64 units = 1;
  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

Comment: Why mix protobuf and ignite? They two independent serialization technologies. Typically you can serialize protobuf to and from a string and transport that (or use combination of protobuf and gRPC for communication between C++ server and Java client)

Comment: Let's say it's just the requirement. Protobuf is the format of our source data. We need to decode and then encode to the format that ignite accepts.

Comment: Can ignite serialize strings (I don't know ignite)? You can serialize/deserialize to and from strings using protobuf.  https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/ (`SerializeToString` somewhere halfway the page)

Comment: Yes, if we store seialized string, then problem would be easy.  Ignite seems have the support for the decimal when it comes to c++ thin client, but I just can't find it. https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/data-types#decimal